# Calculate focus to map world point on imageplane

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, focus, camera-calibration

I try to calculate the focus value to map a world point on to image plane.
I use raspberry pi camera v2. I did get the camera matrix from opencv it gives me for fx and fy 204. Got nearly the same value by measuring at known distance and size of object.
But when I use  a formular I get wrong values.
My formular is

```
Fpix=sensorsize_pix * focus_mm/sensorsize_mm=1pix*focus_mm/pixsize_mm
```

I'm using as values:
320x240 image.
Image is taken with 640x480 resolution and then binned 2x2 in Software.
Because the image is already binned by driver I would have a total binning of 4x4.
The original pixel size 1.4um and focus 3.00mm
Which would give me a binned pixelsize of 5.6um.

So I would calculate

```
Fpix=1pix*3.0mm/0.0056mm=536pix
```

which is a huge difference to 204pix
The specification for the sensor can be found here[link](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html)
As I would consider opencv and measurements as correct. Something must be wrong with my formular.

Comment: How do you performed the calibration with opencv? What is the calculation you did for measuring an object at known distance, and what exactly is your "nearly" result?

Comment: To measure the focus I took a chessboard with known square sizes and aligned it roughly in parallel to sensor edges. Then I made a photo in different known distances. Then I counted the pixels of the projected chessboard on image plane.

Comment: For opencv I just used the calibration source code which comes with opencv. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

Comment: With 640x480 image, the binning factor is 4x4, and with your software shrinking, the factor should now be 8x8. Then the Fpix is now 268 pix. Much closer!

Comment: That would be great. But the tables are a bit confusing. The second one shows the modes for v2 camera. And there it is 2x2 for 640x480